# Express template not linking to scripts, css, or images

Tags: javascript, html, css, express

Using Express, I run the index.html file but cannot get the css, js or images to link up correctly. No images showing, css and js not linking.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>

img/logo.png
```

I have the following directory structure:

```
root
    app.js
    package.json
    node_modules
    assets
        img
        css
        js
        templates
            theme1
                css
                fonts
                img
                js
                index.html
                about.html
                services.html
                news.html
                contact.html
```

In app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    //res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/assets/templates/theme1/index.html'));
});

app.get('/about/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/assets/templates/theme1/about.html'));
});

app.get('/services/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/assets/templates/theme1/services.html'));
});

app.get('/services/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/assets/templates/theme1/news.html'));
});

app.get('/contact/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/assets/templates/theme1/contact.html'));
});

app.listen(3000);
```

need better understanding of `app.get` and `app.use` as well as `res.sendFile`

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it's not working because you're not telling Express to serve the files you want (the js and css and so on).

First you want to setup a static route using the [static middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html):

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/assets'));`

At that point, everything in the 'assets' directory will be served relative to your root URL. So `/img/someimage.jpg` is the correct URL for it.

Comment: how do I set up the app.js file with app.use? do I still need the app.get and app.sendfile?

Comment: Depends.  if you want to keep the behavior where a request to /about returns the file on the file system at assets/templates/theme1/about.html, then it's probably easier to keep doing what you're doing nothing and just add my recommended change before all your app.get declarations.